# Feign Client URL with forward slashes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am using Feign Client and want to pass these URLS with only 1 mapping:

- /123/shirt
- /456/shirt X/L (notice the forward slash is part of query)
- /789/100% cotton (special character)

The following mappings do not work for me:

```
@GetMapping("/{type}/{name}"
List<Item> getItem(
    @PathVariable("type") Long type,
    @PathVariable("name") String name
);
```

```
@GetMapping("/{type}/{name:.*}"
List<Item> getItem(
    @PathVariable("type") Long type,
    @PathVariable("name") String name
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you URL encode the slash `%2F`

Comment: encoding does not work too. I tried /456/shirt%20X%2FL